# Get the substring between two substrings in a string [Javascript]

Tags: javascript, regex, string

### Get 3 or 57 in these examples

I have a list of objects that contain JSON values of these:
For some reason I will skip, the result will be as follows and I want to get the value of the CubicMillimeters by using Regex. How will I do this?

```
var json1 = "{
    "CubicMillimeters": 3,
    "Longtitude": 342.152345,
    "Latitude": 321.332331
}"
var json2 = "{
    "CubicMillimeters": 57,
    "Longtitude": 342.152345,
    "Latitude": 321.332331
}"
```

Thanks :D Greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: [`JSON#parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) could help ...

Comment: `JSON.parse(thatString).CubicMillimeters`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) seems to be the right approche.

But if you really want (for some reason) the regex solution, here it is:

```js
var json = '{"CubicMillimeters": 3,"Longtitude": 342.152345, "Latitude": 321.332331 }',
     reg = /"CubicMillimeters":\s*(.*?),/;
console.log(json.match(reg)[1]);
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/L6OZR5/1) with explanation